# A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'UserCredentialPlatform' doesn't allow null

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.1.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:272:7: Error: 'qthrow' isn't a type.
qthrow convertPlatformException(e);
^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.1.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:272:14: Error: Expected ';' after this.
qthrow convertPlatformException(e);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.1.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:255:34: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'UserCredentialPlatform' doesn't allow null.

- 'UserCredentialPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_user_credential.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.1.0/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_user_credential.dart').
  Future createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  ^

Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)

this is the error i get when i execute my code in flutter

Comment: update firebase_auth package

Comment: Thank you so much!! it really helped me <3

Answer (score 0):

you can make the version of flutter auth: 2.0.0 without ^ sign. its in the pubspec.yaml file. Just change the version and it runs very well but first build on Xcode. Happy Coding!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).